# How to group rows with duplicate name in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, data-visualization, subset

I am quite new to R and struggling with subsetting datasets.
This is where the dataset came from and how I clean it.

```
board_game_original<- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bryandmartin/STAT302/master/docs/Projects/project1_bgdataviz/board_game_raw.csv")

#tidy up the column of mechanic and category with cSplit function
library(splitstackshape)
mechanic <- board_game$mechanic
board_game_tidy <- cSplit(board_game,splitCols=c("mechanic","category"), sep = ",", direction = "long")
```

here's my code trying to extract two columns: category, and average complexities.

```
summary_category <- summary(board_game_tidy$category)
top_5_category <- summary_category[1:5]

complexity_top_5_category <- board_game_tidy %>% 
        group_by(category) %>%
        select(average_complexity) %>%
        filter(category == c("Abstract Strategy Action / Dexterity", "Adventure", "Age of Reason","American Civil War "))
complexity_top_5_category
```

My final intent: create a data frame with only 2 columns: category and average complexities, and take a mean of the average complexities under the same category name.

What I encountered: I have 5 rows of category, but 30 rows of average complexities. What can I do to take a mean value of all the average complexities under the same category names? All help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it is `filter(category %in% c(...))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. You need `dplyr::summarise()`

```
complexity_top_5_category <- board_game_tidy %>% 
        group_by(category) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(mean_average_complexity = mean(average_complexity, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
        top_n(5, mean_average_complexity) 
        #select(average_complexity) %>% # you don't need this
        #filter(category == c("Abstract Strategy Action / Dexterity", "Adventure", "Age of Reason","American Civil War "))
complexity_top_5_category
```

You don't *have* to include `dplyr::` before `summarise()`. However, some other common packages have their versions of summarise() so it's safer to be specific.

You can use `top_n()` to automatically select the top *n* categories, instead of using `filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` the values for top 5 category, then `group_by` `category` and take `mean` of `average_complexity`.

```
library(dplyr)

board_game_tidy %>% 
  filter(category %in% names(top_5_category)) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(average_complexity = mean(average_complexity))

# category           average_complexity
#  <fct>                           <dbl>
#1 Abstract Strategy               0.844
#2 Action / Dexterity              0.469
#3 Adventure                       1.25 
#4 Age of Reason                   1.95 
#5 American Civil War              1.68
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering! I tried your code and it shows:Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. x object 'top_5_category' not found ℹ Input `..1` is `category %in% names(top_5_category)`.

Comment: @harperzhu `top_5_category` is present in your post itself. Did you run that?